# Keras:How to get weights, make weights become 1D array, then make weights shape become initial shape?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I want to do some experiment. and i need to get Keras model weights, make it 1D array , and make the shape like initial shape

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense( 4, input_dim = 5 ,activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'))
# Add an output layer with 10 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(2))
# Configure a model for mean-squared error regression.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
              loss='mse',       # mean squared error
              metrics=['mae'])  # mean absolute error

weights = (model.get_weights())

#make weight  become 1D array

#maka 1D array become like inital shape

model.set_weights(weights)
```

why iwant to do this ?
because i want to do some mutation using other module, that's necessary to pass 1D array

how to do this ?

as we know the shape of Keras model weights look like this

```
[array([[-0.24053234,  0.4722855 ,  0.29863954,  0.22805429],
       [ 0.45101106, -0.00229341, -0.6142864 , -0.2751704 ],
       [ 0.159172  ,  0.43983865,  0.61577237,  0.24255097],
       [ 0.24160242,  0.422235  ,  0.8066592 , -0.2711717 ],
       [-0.30763668, -0.4841219 ,  0.767977  ,  0.23558974]],
      dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.24129152, -0.4890638 ,  0.18787515],
       [ 0.8663894 , -0.09163451, -0.86416066],
       [-0.01754427,  0.32654428, -0.78837514],
       [ 0.589849  ,  0.5886531 ,  0.27824092]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.8456359 , -0.26292562],
       [-1.0447757 , -0.43539298],
       [ 1.0835328 , -0.43536085]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: what are you tring to do with the weights? might want to just keep a compy of the weights if you are not changing them and use a copy for manipulating

Comment: i want to do some mutation

Comment: just to make clear, you want to put the changed weights back into the model? please add more description to what you are trying to do, eg. why make 1d, why back, what manipulation of data.. etc

Comment: ok , i edited the description